# Strange Face in pose mode

Tags: armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups, pose-mode

My model is acting strange in pose mode. Its a shark and when I move it I see a piece sticking out[image]

I already did the weigth painting again and even changed the vertex group of that bone. I cleared the vertex groep and added it manuall but still the strange bit stays. Does anyone know what's going wrong

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I guess my laptop is broken. I retried it on my PC and it works :S strange I do have a new problem now. The face orientation in blender looks fine. only in unity it isnt herse the file:  [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/645e579d423147ffbe7aa1a4290ee591)

Comment: The mesh of the tail is not connected properly. There are inner faces and the edge flow is broken. If you rotate the middle bone, the tail will look like it was cut off and put back in completely wrong. You can delete the inner faces and use the *bridge loop* operation. But the edge flow still will be wonky. I did not experience the error in the screenshot.

Comment: Thnx. I thixed it. I cut of the tail and saved it in a different file. so I had a file without the tail and 1 with only the tail. than I ctrl+J them and added the bones again :p